# Product of two coprime conductors is equal to the conductor of the product of the Dirichlet characters

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, characters

Let $\chi$ and $\psi$ be two Dirichlet characters of conductors $f_{\chi}$ and $f_{\psi}$ respectively. If $f_{\chi}$ and $f_{\psi}$ are relatively prime, then we have to show that $f_{\chi\psi}$ = $f_{\chi}$$f_{\psi}$. Do I have to use the Chinese remainder theorem to prove it? Somehow, I am not getting the proof. Give me some ideas about how to proceed.

Comment: Is this homework?  What have you determined so far?

Comment: This is an exercise I've found in the book "Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields" by Lawrence Washington. I have obtained that $f_{\chi}{\psi}$ divides $f_{\chi}f_{\psi}$ but I am unable to show the other direction.

Comment: Are you able to show that $f_\chi$ divides $f_{\chi\psi}$?

Comment: No. If this is done, then the problem is solved.

Comment: it is obvious that $\chi \psi$ is $f_\chi f_\psi$ periodic, and by definition $\chi \psi (n m) = \chi \psi(n) \ \chi \psi(m)$ i.e. it is completely multiplicative. what to say more ? that $\chi \psi(1) = 1$, obvious too